# Problems with XML Last child fill (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a Problem in XML and i dont know how to solve it..

What i want to do:

I have an Activity and in it i have a PagerViewer and Control Buttons for the Pager .
I want to load the Control Layout on the bottom and the Viewpager on the Top and it should fill the rest of the layout.

I want it to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PgJJ.jpg

This is my actual code:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="410dp"
     android:layout_gravity="top" >

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>  
     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp" >

          <Button
            android:id="@+id/pre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Pre" />

        <ZoomControls
            android:id="@+id/zoomControls1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Next" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

edit: thanks to gio for helping to edit my code properly.

Comment: please add your code in your post.

Comment: replace your image with code by `code block`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure I got your problem, but here's my guess.

1. Avoid using `fill_parent` anywhere; use `match_parent` instead;
2. For the LinearLayout that holds the ViewPager, replace `410dp` with `0dp` and set `android:layout_weight="1"`;
3. Replace `android:layout_height="match_parent"` with `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for the LinearLayout that holds your butttons.

Point 3. will make your LinearLayout be tall just enough to show its content; point 2. will make your first LinearLayout fill remaining space. Same can be done to the `ViewPager`, if needed.

As for the margins I see in your drawing, you can set an `android:padding` attribute on the LinearLayout that holds the ViewPager .

Comment: This won't leave any room for the buttons.

Comment: Yep if i do this my buttons will dissapear

Comment: Right. Edited my answer @Kandey.